# How to Remove Parent Page menu slug from WordPress Submenus?

Tags: menus

By default, WordPress adds a parent menu slug to submenu items if there are three or more nested submenus. I want to remove that.

[image: Menu having 3 nested sub menu]

For example, in the above case, the "service" menu has three submenu items:

1.Brand strategy
2. Website Design
3. Digital Marketing
Each of these submenu items may have further submenus.

When clicking on any submenu item like "Website Design," WordPress generates the default URL structure as follows:

Default URL is. : xyz.com/services/website-design 
URL that I want : xyz.com/website-design

How can I achieve this? Please guide

Thank you!

Comment: The URL is based on the selected parent page, which is completely independent from the menu. Unless your theme is doing something, just don't give the page a parent page and the URL will be what you want, but you should be able to organise it in the menu however you want.